# fpdf error, Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array - Cannot modify header information

Tags: php, fpdf

I am looking for some help wit fpdf.

Funny thing is that the scripts have been working perfectly, until the domain move and since I have various errors on all pdf exports.

```
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in /home/compaxit/public_html/members-area/transactions/general/basic/change_registered_office/data.php on line 88
```

I get many warnings like the above on various lines.

Finally I get this warning:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /data.php:88) in /pdf_includes/fpdf.php on line 1017
FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file.
```

I have already tried some of the solutions found here but had no success so far.

as requested the first 10 lines and last 10 lines...

```
require('../../../../../pdf_includes/fpdf.php');
session_start();
//echo $_POST['test_1']; die;
$_SESSION['test_1'] = str_replace("  ",' ',$_SESSION['test_1']);
$_SESSION['test_2'] = str_replace("  ",' ',$_SESSION['test_2']);
$_SESSION['test_3'] = str_replace("  ",' ',$_SESSION['test_3']);
$_SESSION['test_4'] = str_replace("  ",' ',$_SESSION['test_4']);
$_SESSION['test_5'] = str_replace("  ",' ',$_SESSION['test_5']);
$_SESSION['test_6'] = str_replace("  ",' ',$_SESSION['test_6']);
$data = $_REQUEST['editor1'];

first 11 lines :)

last few:

$pdf = new PDF();
// First page
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetLeftMargin(19);
$pdf->SetRightMargin (15);
$pdf->Cell(10);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->WriteHTML($data);
$pdf->Output();
```

both do of course contain the open php tag, also the following line receives the data from a previous form.
$data = $_REQUEST['editor1'];

then the lines 75 - 102 which is I believe the error line involved if I am correct in thinking its line 88...

```
        // Text
        if($this->HREF)
            $this->PutLink($this->HREF,$e);

            elseif($this->ALIGN=='center'){
                $ttt++;                             
                $this->SetFontSize(11); 
                if($ttt==2 || $ttt==3){                     
                    $this->MultiCell(0,5,trim($e),0,'C',0);

                } else {                        
                    $this->MultiCell(0,2,trim($e),0,'C',0);
                }
            }
        else {
            $this->SetFontSize(10);
            if(in_array(trim($e),$arrSR)){
                $this->SetFontSize(12);

            } else {
                $this->SetFontSize(10);
            }

            if(in_array(trim($e),$dirct)){
                if($jk==0){
                    $y = $this->GetY();
                    $this->SetY($y - 2.00);                 
                }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Please give the mentioned php files with at least 10 lines of context before and after the error line. Otherwise nobody can really help you.

Comment: what's `$arrSR`? Where are you getting it from?

Comment: yes either your $arrSR variable or $dirct variable are not arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your PHP configuration. You are outputting warnings to the output stream. This affects the PDF output. You need to disable the warnings.

An easy change would be to go into your php.ini file, and look for "error_reporting"

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING
```

Alternatively you can set it yourself in the PHP code at the top of your file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_NOTICE | E_WARNING));
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Alternatively you could fix the error by initializing $arrSR and $dirct before their use

```
$arrSR = array();
$dirct = array();
```

Comment: It's better to fix error(warning in this case), then just make it silent by config

Comment: error reporting should be silent on production servers always. You could fix the error but obviously passing false as an array because it happens to be empty is not a huge deal.